# Maximum allowed value for a numpy data type

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with numpy arrays of a range of data types (uint8, uint16, int16, etc.). I would like to be able to check whether a number can be represented within the limits of an array for a given datatype. I am imagining something that looks like:

```
>>> im.dtype
dtype('uint16')
>>> dtype_max(im.dtype)
65535
>>> dtype_min(im.dtype)
0
```

Does something like this exist? By the way, I feel like this has to have been asked before, but my search came up empty, and all of the "similar questions" appear to be unrelated.

Edit: Of course, now that I've asked, one of the "related" questions does have the answer. Oops.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

```py
min_value = np.iinfo(im.dtype).min
max_value = np.iinfo(im.dtype).max
```

docs:

- [`np.iinfo`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.iinfo.html#numpy-iinfo) (machine limits for integer types)
- [`np.finfo`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html#numpy-finfo) (machine limits for floating point types)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this. For consistency with my question, the argument in iinfo should be im.dtype, not im.

Comment: Is there a simple way to do this without knowing if the type is float or int (thus having to choose between iinfo and finfo) ? Currently I'm using a try/catch, it's a bit cumbersome

Comment: @gdelab Instead of using try/catch, you can also use  `issubclass(dtype, np.integer)` and `issubclass(dtype, np.floating)` for branching and selecting either `np.iinfo` or `np.finfo`.

Answer (score 23):

You're looking for `numpy.iinfo` for integer types. Documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.iinfo.html#numpy-iinfo).

There's also `numpy.finfo` for floating point types. Documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html#numpy-finfo).