# Why do I get an overflow error multiplying Numpy product outputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I've encountered an overflow warning as a result of multiplying the output of Numpy products that I'm looking to understand. A simplified version of their actual use within my larger project is detailed below:

```
import numpy as np

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self,
                 array_1,
                 array_2):

        # Assigning arrays to be used in later methods
        self.array_1 = array_1
        self.array_2 = array_2

        # Assigning some scaling factors to be used in later methods.
        self.value_1 = np.prod(self.array_1.shape)
        self.value_2 = np.prod(self.array_2.shape)
        print("Numpy Product Assignment: {0}, {1}".format(self.value_1, self.value_2))

        # Alternative assignment of scaling factors
        self.alt_value_1 = self.array_1.shape[0] * self.array_1.shape[1]
        self.alt_value_2 = self.array_2.shape[0] * self.array_2.shape[1]
        print("Regular Product Assignment: {0}, {1}".format(self.alt_value_1, self.alt_value_2))

        pass

    def mymethod(self):
        print("Direct Multiplication: {0}".format(80160 * 262144))
        print("Numpy Product Multiplication: {0}".format(self.value_1 * self.value_2))
        print("Regular Product Multiplcation {0}".format(self.alt_value_1 * self.alt_value_2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_array_1 = np.zeros([512, 512], dtype=complex)
    test_array_2 = np.zeros([1002, 80], dtype=complex)

    test_class = MyClass(test_array_1, test_array_2)
    test_class.mymethod()
```

Including the use with the class structure for completeness, though heavily edited down to the bare minimum. If I run this code (on Python 3.6.0) I get the following output:

```
C:/somepath/scratch.py:247: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
  print("Numpy Product Multiplication: {0}".format(self.value_1 * self.value_2))
Numpy Product Assignment: 262144, 80160
Regular Product Assignment: 262144, 80160
Direct Multiplication: 21013463040
Numpy Product Multiplication: -461373440
Regular Product Multiplcation 21013463040

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Clearly I can get around the problem using the regular multiplication, but I would like to understand why there is a problem and if it can be fixed as is. I think there is some *dtype=X* subtlety that I have missed, so my question is what is causing these overflow errors?

Comment: I think the problem occurs because `numpy` uses c-type integers internally, while the regular multiplication uses `python` integers, which have a much larger [maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7604981/2454357).

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23189557/2454357).

Comment: @ThomasKühn "Much larger maximum value" Indeed. Integers have in Python3 theoretically no maximum value, only your system sets the limits.

Comment: @Piinthesky Yes, I formulated it badly, but the answer I linked includes that information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like an overflow caused by 32 integers. You can convert your values to 64 bit like this:

```
    self.value_1 = np.prod(self.array_1.shape, dtype=np.int64)
    self.value_2 = np.prod(self.array_2.shape, dtype=np.int64)
```

Numpy automatically selects a 32 bit integer type if the values used for array construction are small enough. During multiplication they are not automatically cast to 64 bit.

Comment: So it uses the size of the np.prod result to determine the output dtype, not any properties of the input array, unless you have defined the dtype argument within np.prod?

Comment: Actually, `prod`normally uses the properties of the input array - but you pass in `array.shape`, which is a tuple. The tuple needs to be converted to an array, and this conversion looks at the values. (Oh, and it looks like `prod` takes a `dtype` argument that you can use instead of calling `.astype` on the result.)

Comment: Ah I had missed that shape is a tuple, but that does make sense. Thanks.