# float and double max value check in python

Tags: python

I am trying to validate float and double values using python. Since python supports large numbers, I would like to do validate the given number in within the range of float(32 bit floating point representation) or double(64 bit floating point representation)? How can I achieve it?

```
def is_int(x):
    int_max_value = 2^31 - 1
    int_min_value = -2^31
    if int_min_value <= x <= int_max_value:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def is_float(x):
    # need to implement this
    pass
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you want validated, and what the corresponding results should be?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of [What is the maximum float in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477283) or [Maximum allowed value for a numpy data type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23189506) (Python float values are always double, and I don't think [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) provides float limits information, so you may resort to NumPy for other precision types).

Comment: Note that floating numbers include positive and negative infinity, so technically _any_ number would always be within range.

Comment: This is going to be difficult to do using builtin types since [floats _are_ doubles in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6663292/4739755)

Answer (score 1):

One way to reliably get the limits of floating point formats is to construct the values from their binary representation with [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html).

```
import struct
FLOAT_MAX = struct.unpack('>f', b'\x7f\x7f\xff\xff')
FLOAT_MIN = struct.unpack('>f', b'\xff\x7f\xff\xff')
MAX_DOUBLE = struct.unpack('>d', b'\x7f\xef\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff')
MIN_DOUBLE = struct.unpack('>d', b'\xff\xef\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff')
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution like below after referring [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/type-float?view=vs-2019)

```
DOUBLE_MAX = 1.7976931348623158E+308     # 64 bit floating point max value
DOUBLE_MIN = 2.2250738585072014E-308     # 64 bit floating point max value
def is_double(value):
    return DOUBLE_MIN <= value <= DOUBLE_MAX

FLOAT_MAX = 3.402823466E+38     # 32 bit floating point max value
FLOAT_MIN = 1.175494351E-38     # 32 bit floating point max value
def is_float(value):
    return FLOAT_MIN <= value <= FLOAT_MAX

is_float(123e20)
is_double(123e20)

is_float(123e203)
is_double(123e203)

is_float(123e2030)
is_double(123e2030)
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to write `if condition: return True else: return False`, this is logically equivalent to `return condition`.

Comment: This won't work on all floats. For example `x = FLOAT_MIN - 1` returns False from `is_float`, but python states that x is indeed a float `type(x) -> float`

Comment: I am not looking for the python datatype. I am actually looking for pyspark datatypes as it has float and double datatypes explicitly. So I need to validate them before inserting them into frame

Comment: You should include that in your question then as that's some pretty important context